# "pygettext" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом

Tags: python, gettext

Я просто уже замучался разбираться с gettext.

Помогите пожалуйста!

Мне необходимо сделать приложение на двух языках  EN и RU

Все делаю по гайду https://habr.com/ru/post/73554/

Может что то устарело.

Далее по гайду как у меня:

Cодержимое: `mary.py`

```
import gettext

gettext.install('mary', './locale', unicode=True)

name = _("Mary")
animal = _("lamb")

print(_("%s had a little %s") % (name, animal))
```

Ввод PyCHARM Terminal:`py mary.py`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pythonProjects\SkyrimSE Magic Config\mary.py", line 4, in <module>
    gettext.install('mary', './locale', unicode=True)
TypeError: install() got an unexpected keyword argument 'unicode'
```

---- Убираю `, unicode=True`

Ввод PyCHARM Terminal:`py mary.py`

```
C:\pythonProjects\project37>py mary.py
Mary had a little lamb
```

Работает... хорошо...

Далее по гайду сказано:

### Запускаем pygettext: `pygettext mary.py` В одном каталоге с нашей программой появился файл messages.pot, содержащий следующее...

У меня просто открывается файл с содержимым самого pygettext.py

ни какого файла *.pot не создает

Просто бред.

Начал искать причину: Нашел в переменных среды
C:\Python3.9.2\Tools\i18n

Удалил, перезагрузился.

Ввод PyCHARM Terminal: `pygettext mary.py`

pygettext mary.py
"pygettext" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Помогите решить проблему.

Comment: Перескачайте модуль pygettext вы возможно его повредили

Comment: Да я полностью скачал python по новой и установил. PATH проверил, все впорядке. Данные команды работают, только если pygettext.py находятся в самом проекте, а так быть не должно.

Comment: А стоп, измените название фйла, из-за такого название может и ошибка вилетить.

Comment: Я так и не разобрался почему у меня не работает, а так же на другом ПК тоже самое. я вообще не понимаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если еще актуально, то можно pot файл создать вот так в Cmd:

```
py -3.11 C:\Python311\Tools\i18n\pygettext.py -d myapp myapp.py
```

Соответственно версия и путь у Вас будут свои.